# Clang errors after deletion in /usr/bin and copying back

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, clang

Please don't ask me what on earth got into me deleting `clang` from the `/usr/bin` folder...I got weird error messages and couldn't find anything on the web...

However, I deleted `clang`, tried reinstalling Xcode + developer tools, but `clang` wasn't installed again. So I searched inside the Xcode folder and found it in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang`

So, I copied this (and `clang++`) back to my `/usr/bin` folder, but now I'm getting weird error messages again, e.g:

```
fatal error: 'stdarg.h' file not found
#include <stdarg.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

Any idea how I could fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to link it instead of copying

```
ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang /usr/bin/clang
```

Comment: Now it's possible...had to wait for 8mins after you replied :D